# Return List of Class Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Currently I am only able to return a list of strings for a custom class. I need to be able to return the objects themselves to pass tests. Please note, I am not allowed to adjust the class itself.

Current output(s):

1. String representation of the Class Objects
   `["player_result(name='Erik', points=2.5, resistance_points=4.0, sonnenborn_berger=3.0, black=2.0)", "player_result(name='Daniel', points=2.0, resistance_points=5.5, sonnenborn_berger=3.25, black=1.0)", "player_result(name='Charlotte', points=2.0, resistance_points=3.5, sonnenborn_berger=2.25, black=1.0)", "player_result(name='Anna', points=1.0, resistance_points=5.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.5, black=2.0)", "player_result(name='Bob', points=1.0, resistance_points=5.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.5, black=1.0)", "player_result(name='Femke', points=0.5, resistance_points=4.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.0, black=2.0)"]`
2. Object values not coming through properly.
   `[<chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f0325c0>, <chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f032aa0>, <chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f032980>, <chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f032860>, <chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f032a40>, <chess.player_result object at 0x7fe94f032830>]`
3. Desired output (should just be the objects and the underlying data):
   `[player_result(name='Erik', points=2.5, resistance_points=4.0, sonnenborn_berger=3.00, black=2), player_result(name='Daniel', points=2.0, resistance_points=5.5, sonnenborn_berger=3.25, black=1), player_result(name='Charlotte', points=2.0, resistance_points=3.5, sonnenborn_berger=2.25, black=1), player_result(name='Anna', points=1.0, resistance_points=5.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.50, black=2), player_result(name='Bob', points=1.0, resistance_points=5.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.50, black=1), player_result(name='Femke', points=0.5, resistance_points=4.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.00, black=2)]`

```
# DON'T MODIFY THIS CLASS
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class player_result:
    def __init__(self, name: str, points: float, resistance_points: float, sonnenborn_berger: float, black: int):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
        self.resistance_points = resistance_points
        self.sonnenborn_berger = sonnenborn_berger
        self.black = black

    def __str__(self):
        return 'player_result(name=\'' + self.name + '\', points=' + str(self.points) + ', resistance_points=' + \
               str(self.resistance_points) + ', sonnenborn_berger=' + str(self.sonnenborn_berger) + \
               ', black=' + str(self.black) + ')'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.points == other.points and \
            self.resistance_points == other.resistance_points and \
            self.sonnenborn_berger == other.sonnenborn_berger and self.black == other.black


def determine_output(input: str):
    create_player_and_round_obj(input)


def create_player_and_round_obj(input_string):
    player_obj = {}
    rounds_obj = {}
    curr_round = 0
    round_list = []
    for line in input_string.splitlines():
        if " " in line:
            round_list = line.split(" ")
            rounds_obj[curr_round] = round_list
            curr_round += 1
        elif len(line) < 1:
            continue
        else:
            player_obj[line] = {'pt': 0.0, 'rp': 0.0, 'sb': 0.0, 'b': 0.0}
    calculate_reg_points(player_obj, rounds_obj)


def calculate_reg_points(player_obj, rounds_obj):
    for results in rounds_obj.values():
        indexed_result = np.array(results)
        if indexed_result[2] == '1':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[0]]['pt'] += 1.0
            # points for playing black
            player_obj[results[1]]['b'] += 1.0
        elif indexed_result[2] == '0':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[1]]['pt'] += 1.0
            # points for playing black
            player_obj[results[1]]['b'] += 1.0
        elif indexed_result[2] == '0.5':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[0]]['pt'] += 0.5
            player_obj[results[1]]['pt'] += 0.5
            # points for playing black
            player_obj[results[1]]['b'] += 1.0
        # print(results)
    calculate_rp(player_obj, rounds_obj)


def calculate_rp(player_obj, rounds_obj):
    # setup opponents dict
    opponents = {}
    for k, v in rounds_obj.items():
        if v[0] not in opponents.keys():
            opponents[v[0]] = []

    # for each player, add all opponents to list in opponents dictionary
    for player in opponents.keys():
        for rnd in rounds_obj.values():
            if player in rnd:
                for item in rnd:
                    not_it = [player, '1', '0', '0.5']
                    if item not in not_it:
                        opponents[player] += [item]

    # add rp to each player based on their opponents pt totals
    for player_name, points_dict in player_obj.items():
        for playr, opp_list in opponents.items():
            if player_name == playr:
                for opp in opp_list:
                    player_obj[player_name]["rp"] += player_obj[opp]["pt"]
    calculate_sb(player_obj, rounds_obj)


def calculate_sb(player_obj, rounds_obj):
    for results in rounds_obj.values():
        indexed_result = np.array(results)
        if indexed_result[2] == '1':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[0]]['sb'] += 1.0 * player_obj[results[1]]['pt']
        elif indexed_result[2] == '0':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[1]]['sb'] += 1.0 * player_obj[results[0]]['pt']
        elif indexed_result[2] == '0.5':
            # points for winning/losing/tie
            player_obj[results[0]]['sb'] += 0.5 * player_obj[results[1]]['pt']
            player_obj[results[1]]['sb'] += 0.5 * player_obj[results[0]]['pt']
    sort_players(player_obj)


def sort_players(player_obj):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player_obj, orient='index')
    df = df.sort_values(by=['pt', 'rp', 'sb', 'b'], ascending=[
                        False, False, False, False])

    results = df.to_records()
    final_list = []
    for result in results:
        h = player_result(name=result[0], points=result[1],
                          resistance_points=result[2], sonnenborn_berger=result[3], black=result[4])
        final_list.append(h)

    print(final_list)
    return final_list
```

Comment: Have you tried writing `__repr__` function as well on your class?

Comment: "_should just be the objects_" - It's not possible to print the `str()` output in the list without quotes

Comment: You could `print('[' + ', '.join(final_list) + ']')`, but I don't think that's what you are supposed to do...

Comment: Why are you doing the thing with `test_list` where you turn everything into a string?  Why not just `return final_list` which is the actual list of objects?  And why does `calculate_sb` call `sort_players` but not do anything with the result?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I cannot edit the class itself.

Comment: @Samwise, I was just attempting different return results at the time. I cleaned up the code and it is currently what I have in place.

Comment: Also for those wanting more info on why/how.

https://phoenix.labs.vu.nl/assessment/files/assignment_two.pdf

Comment: I'm pretty sure output 2 is what you actually want. The class isn't set up correctly to print out nicely from inside of a list, since the list will call `__repr__` rather than `__str__` on each value in its contents. But that doesn't really matter if you just want to return the objects themselves. How they print out is irrelevant.

Comment: FWIW, I suggest removing `print(final_list)` and call `print(calculate_sb(...))` other places. Regardless, as mentioned, `__repr__` is what will "print objects" within a list, so you **need to** modify the class

Comment: @Blckknght, I think you are right too, but I need to format it in the way shown in the attached PDF. I am a bit at a loss here if they don't want us touching the class :/

Comment: Are you *sure* you need it to print out pretty? Or do you just need to create equivalent objects to those that would be created by the expression in the assignment? I think your instructors were just using lazy shorthand in the assignment, and didn't actually check how a list of `player_result` objects would print out.

Comment: @Blckknght, sadly I need test_chess.py to pass (and there is an online grader I will need to submit to as well). I am currently passing none of the tests due to the formatting (the data is all correct, thankfully)

Comment: current github repo: https://github.com/CEckelberry/uni_training

Comment: I suspect the grading error is caused by something else, not the output. Looking at the assignment, it seems to want `determine_output()` to return the list of objects. Currently that function returns `None`, since you don't has a `return` statement in it. Fix that (probably by having each function `return` the value returned by whatever it calls) and you might be in business.

Comment: @Blckknght, that was it!!! Thank you so much. I had forgotten all about the first method since I didn't do anything in there formula wise.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the grading error is caused by something else, not the output. Looking at the assignment, it seems to want determine_output() to return the list of objects. Currently, that function returns None, since you don't has a return statement in it. Fix that (probably by having each function return the value returned by whatever it calls) and you might be in business. – Blckknght